# How to take an array and convert all numbers to other numbers. 'JAVA'

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a GPA calculator in java. Once I have all the grades in my array I would like to have another array that puts all the GPA's into the same size array.

For example arrayA = [90, 95, 80, 87, 100] ....

I want to be able to convert those numbers to arrayB and make it equal [3.7, 4.0, 2.7, 3.3, 4.3]

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 Coleman Strauss
 GPA Calculator
 March 12, 2015
 */
public class GPACalculator
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int numClasses;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] myArrayGrades;
        double[] myArrayGPA;


        System.out.println("Please enter in the amount of classes you have:   ");
        numClasses = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Alright so you have " + numClasses + " classes.");

        myArrayGrades = new double[numClasses];

        for (int i=0; i < numClasses; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter all your grades in a row!");

        }
        System.out.println(myArrayGrades);
    }
}
```

Comment: tell us the GPA rankings you want. Different schools do it different ways e.g. Grade -> 90 <= A <= 100, 80<=B<90, C...

Comment: I just want to know the syntax

Comment: Just cast to double and divide by 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, really. Test if the sizes are the same, and if so, convert. Don't forget to initialize the arrays

```
if(arrayA.size() == arrayB.size()){
//do nothing
}
else{
exit; //array sizes are mismatched and will cause OutOfBounds exception
}

for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++){
arrayB[i] = arrayA[i]*GPAConditional; /*GPAConditional is the constant conversion factor used to convert grades into GPA, ultimately defined by you*/ 
}
```

Note that changes to arrayA's elements change arrayB's elements!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a map like

```
Map<Double, Double> gpas = new HashMap<>();
gpas(100d, 4d);
gpas(90d, 3.5);
```

etc.

Then you can just loop through your original array and retrieve the corresponding gpa from the map and fill up the second array.

```
int i = 0;
for(Integer grade : myArrayGrades){
myArrayGPA[i++] = map.get(grade);
}
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get all the values I needed into the array. Instead of using two arrays, I converted the grades to the GPA instantly and stored them into the array like so:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    /**
     Coleman Strauss
     GPA Calculator
     March 12, 2015
     */
    public class GPACalculator
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) 
        {
            int numClasses;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[] myArrayGrades;
            double sumGPA = 0;


    System.out.println("Please enter in the amount of classes you have: ");
    numClasses = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Alright so you have " + numClasses + " classes.");

    myArrayGrades = new double[numClasses];


    for (int i=0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter all your grades in a row!");
        myArrayGrades[i] = scan.nextDouble();

        if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 97) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 4.3; 
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 93) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 4.0;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 90) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 3.7;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 87) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 3.3;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 83) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 3.0;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 80) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 2.7;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 77) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 2.3;
        }
         else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 73) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 2.0;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 70) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 1.7;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 67) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 1.3;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 63) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 1.0;
        }
        else if (myArrayGrades[i] >= 60) {
            myArrayGrades[i] = .07;
        }
        else {
            myArrayGrades[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Here are all of your GPA's for each class");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArrayGrades));

    for (int i = 0; i <= numClasses; i ++) {
        myArrayGrades[i] += sumGPA;
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of the GPA's is: " + sumGPA);
```

}
}